# Player moves in a jerky way when riding on a moving platform

Tags: unity, c#, moving-platforms

I have a moving platform script that travels between three positions. This works fine.

I have a script that holds the player to a platform, and this works fine too.

But when I parent my platform that holds my player to an object with the moving platform script, the player's movement is jerky and uneven.

Here are the scripts I'm using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingMultipalPoint : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Vector3 pointB;
    public Vector3 pointC;
    public float Second = 5.0f;
    public float Speed = 3.0f;
    //public float HoldSecond = 5.0f;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Vector3 pointA = transform.position;
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Second);
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointA, pointB, Speed));
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Second);
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointB, pointC, Speed));
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Second);
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointC, pointB, Speed));
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Second);
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointB, pointA, Speed));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator MoveObject(Transform thisTransform, Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, float time)
    {
        float i = 0.0f;
        float rate = 1.0f / time;
        while (i < 1.0f)
        {
            i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
            //newRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
            //transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
            thisTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, i);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This script holds the player to the platform.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HoldPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject target = null;
    private Vector3 offset;
    void Start()
    {
        target = null;
    }
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {
        target = col.gameObject;
        offset = target.transform.position - transform.position;
    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        target = null;
    }
    void LateUpdate()
   {
        if (target != null)
        {
            target.transform.position = transform.position + offset;
        }
   }
}
```

(1st Image) Here is how the moving platform is configured in the Inspector:

(2nd Image) And the holding script:

[image: Screen shot of PLayer & moving Platform]

[Also here recorded video of issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKr8zZZfUSA)

Any ideas how I can keep the movement smooth in this case?

Comment: I understand if English is not your first language, but for not following general formatting practices that are _usually_ the same between languages (for example making the first letter of a sentence capital) this is not a valid excuse.

Comment: you give me down vote for capital mistake. don't be oversmart. if u don't know answer then why u given down vote. Also i said my bad english.

Comment: also give any vote where you know answer.

Comment: Instead of turning this into a personal attack, you could have reformatted your question and I would be happy to lift my downvote.

Comment: @S. Tarık Çetin That's why we have a review queue. There is no need to downvote for trivialities like formatting - someone will spot those and happily edit them away. Also, I don't believe new users can edit! (?)

Comment: @OP I want you to understand that the reason this question already has 2 close votes is because no-one can understand this: "But when Player stay on MovingPlatform while MovingPlatform moving with Player [from here this makes no sense] one position to another position [???]. Its taking tweak [???] (didn't run smoothly). Without Player stay[??? what is "player stay"?] its moving smoothly." You are going to have to find a way to use better English, and/or provide a GIF of the problem in action.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer As far as I know, you can always edit your own question. 

The sentence "That's why we have review queue." is encouraging that it is fine to post a badly formatted question and leave the heavy work to reviewers. It's the OP's job to ask a well-formatted question in the first place.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin I get your viewpoint, but in fact, we earn points for those reviews / edits: That's why I said "happily". To each his own, but my view is that a question should be downvoted for non-superficial reasons, as it often results in the question being permanently hobbled, once it drops below zero.

Comment: @Arcane As far as I know, only the first post of the user gets into the review queue automatically. You also can't make a low quality post and except that someone edits it every time, so in this argument, I'm with S. Tarık Çetin

Comment: @Bálint Fair point on the review queue. I reiterate what I noted about subzero votes and avoiding hobbling questions: people often put a fair amount of time into thinking through what they want to ask, wording their questions, getting and marking screenshots / animations and so on. In this case OP is not even an English speaker. So in favour of "not being an ass", again: downvote questions to below zero only if there is good reason, e.g. lack of research, multi-questions, discussion-oriented etc. But "poor formatting"? That's _petty_.

Comment: @OP "It's taking jerk" do you mean "movement is jerky"? Like platform or player does not move smoothly?

Comment: I don't find this question that unclear  (although a video or animated gif is almost always worthwhile to include when describing a movement or animation glitch). I've tried to update it in an edit. @AlpeshSavaliya, please feel free to adjust my wording if I've misunderstood. You may also want to consider using Rigidbodies and physics with velocities to handle cases like these, as it can provide more consistent handling of movement over time than we get from discrete collision resolution with position updates at a variable framerate.

Comment: @Arcane Engineer yes,but it happen only when platform move with player.

Comment: @DMGregory please check i recorded video of issue.

Comment: please anyone help me. i m stuck at this point plzzz

Comment: Guys also i did animation for Platform move PointA to PointB & attached hold player script but still platform movement is jerky